# Bootstrap-Select : Unable to create a simple select box using bootstrap-select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

As per the documentation :

```
[https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select][1]
```

I have created a `fiddle` at `jsfiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/yugal/TVCDA/6/

**Problem :**

- It shows `tick` for all options
- As if it was multi-select
- Seems weird, what am I missing ?

**Expected :**

- Simple decorated `selectbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't link to github, github is not a CDN

http://jsfiddle.net/TVCDA/7/

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/stylesheets/bootstrap-select.css
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/javascripts/bootstrap-select.js
```

Comment: Strange. You seem to be right since your example is working. But I don't understand why. if it can-not connect then how come `bootstrap-select.js` was working in the first place. Please explain. :(